# Can we use the adverb only at the start of a sentence and followed by a subject?

Tags: adverbs

> Only I need is

Who knows the reason why grammatically or semantically the phrase above is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to use *only* before virtually any word to restrict its reference.

> Only I need to go; everyone else may stay.

But your sentence fragment is ungrammatical, because two verbs follow the apparent subject. Which takes ***I*** as its subject?  If ***I*** is the subject of *need*, then *is* has no evident subject, and its role here is mysterious.

More likely what you mean is something like

> The only thing I need is ...

Note that *only* is not ordinarily used as a nominal, the way *some* and *all* are; it is an adjective or adverb, not a determiner. The only exception that comes to mind is the fixed phrase *my one and only*, which is occasionally used as a noun phrase meaning "the only person I love", especially in song lyrics.

Comment: This is all true. I'll take your word for it it's what OP is asking about (I don't understand the question).

Comment: ...OP's "adverbial" doesn't make me think of "nominals". It makes me think of constructions like *"Only speak when spoken to"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But her title is "Can we use the adverb only at the start of a sentence **and followed by a subject**?", which is the pattern in her fragment - which is fine until you get to *is*.

Comment: Which may indeed support your interpretation. All I'm saying is it's not obvious to me, and I have closevoted as "Unclear". OP gives no indication of what the gibberish example is supposed to mean (but I assume it's not intended to be a *sentence*). But what does OP really want to know, and why? There are an infinite number of non-grammatical strings of words. Why *this* one?